# JQuery.css("display", "block") still ends up inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I check how this piece of code below affect my html live, I see that the `span#error` is faded out and faded in with `display: block` but changes right-after to `display: inline`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#credentials .wrapper button").click(function() {
        $("span#error").fadeOut(300);
        $("span#error").html('<b style="color: #ce1919;">(!)</b> TEST').fadeIn(300).css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

[<kbd>JsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/yfC2B/)

Comment: A Jsfiddle would still be useful as well as your HTML/CSS in your post/

Comment: Updated with simplified JsFiddle

Comment: If this `bug` works in JsFiddle and not your code, then it's something to do with the rest of your code and not this section.

Comment: If your code does not fail on jsFiddle, then it seems that the source of error must be outside of the snippet you provided here. Hence we cannot help due to lack of information...

Comment: @BeatAlex Thanks a lot. You managed to replicate the glitch.

Comment: No worries @KidDiamond

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's fading methods automagically sets the display type that the element has by default.

If you're going to set it to something else, do it after the fading has completed, or use a method that doesn't set the display property, such as `fadeTo` or `animate()`

```
$(function() {
    $("#credentials .wrapper button").click(function() {
        $("#error").fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).html('<b style="color: #ce1919;">(!)</b> TEST')
                   .fadeIn(300, function() {
                       $(this).css("display", "block");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The real answer would be to just use a block element

```
<div id='error'>Error</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfC2B/1/)

Comment: OP's original method actually works better. People please look at (or JsFiddle) the code before upvoting it as 'correct'.

Comment: This is in no way a 'dig' at you, @adeneo, I'm just saying if you run this code and OP's code in JsFiddle, OP's code looks nicer.

Comment: @BeatAlex - That's because in the OP's fiddle the element starts out as hidden, and there would be no need for the first fadeOut, so I assumed the element wasn't hidden by default, otherwise what would be the point ?

Comment: @adeneo The reason I'm fading out, is because there might be other parts of the code that have triggered the error. So I want to make sure to fade it out first before fading in any other error message.

Comment: @KidDiamond - The real question is, why aren't you just using a block element, like a DIV ?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the `inline` type style it does for a moment. But a block element would be better.

Comment: @BeatAlex - No problem, I did eventually see the issue you were pointing out when testing it, the element moved when applying the style in the callback.

Comment: +1 for using a div. I'd actually be inclined to remove the original code and comments and just leave the first line and the stuff after the main code block.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the `fadeIn`-method sets the display variable after fading in. Use the `complete` callback of the `fadeIn`-method to set the *display*-property of the *span* to *block*.

Answer (score 0):

When using fade in, the element will be displayed as his original state. Since you original state is `none`, jQuery will select the default display value of the element, which is in this case `inline`.

In you CSS, if you change the `display` value to `block` and hide the element in a DOM ready handle, everything work fine :

```
$(function() {
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("span#error").fadeOut(300);
        $("span#error").html('<b style="color: #ce1919;">(!)</b> TEST').fadeIn(300).css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfC2B/2/

---

*I'm aware that using block element would be better, I am just telling why it doesnt not currently work.*

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even use `fadeIn` I would just use [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/), since the documentation for `fadeIn` says that it just animates the `opacity` property, to prevent jQuery from messing with the `display` property at all:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("span#error").fadeOut(300).stop();
        $("span#error").stop().html('<b style="color: #ce1919;">(!)</b> TEST').css({'opacity':'0','display':'block'}).animate({opacity:1},1000,function(){});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfC2B/3/